# Restricting Jquery Resize To Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-resizable

I have 2 divs placed inside another div. I want to resize these 2 divs within the main div. I can constraint each div separately using following code.

```
<div id='resizable'>
<div id='div1'></div>
<div id='div2'></div>
</div>

$("#div1").resizable({ containment: '#resizable' });
```

But i want to constraint both divs inside the main container at same time. How can i do this with jquery ?

Comment: Do you want div1 to shrink if div2 expands, and vice-versa?

Comment: no. lets assume div is 100*100 and div2 is 100*100. If i resize the div2 , div1 should still be 100*100 and div2 should be resized in the remaining space.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5817

You can workaround it by having the divs resize each other accordingly. You'll need to adjust this for multiple divs: http://jsbin.com/ewajaw/edit#javascript,html,live

Is that what you want?

Comment: yes the example is right. but when you increase the height of first div the 2nd div goes out of container. I want to prevent that

Comment: In firefox. Try incresing the height of first div to the height of container. Text in the second div goes out

Comment: Oh yeah, now I see. The only thing I can think of is using overflow: hidden. See update here: http://jsbin.com/ewajaw/3/edit

Comment: You need to add overflow:hidden to all divs.

Comment: That want solve my problem. What i want is limit the resize movement so that all divs are within the main container

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried maxWidth :

```
$("#div1").resizable({ containment: '#resizable', maxWidth: ($("#resizable").width() / 2) });
```

Comment: That means it will limit width of each div to 50%. I dont want that. I want to dynamically change the width and height inside the main container.

Comment: Something like jsfiddle where you can drag a line in between and resize both size?

Comment: ya that's actually what i want.

Comment: jsfiddle contains 4 areas. In my case number of divs can be dynamic. It can be 2,3,4,5 ....etc